# How to display the time alone without date in java

Tags: java, string, date, time, split

String Parsing Using Multiple Delimiter

Can I use multiple delimiters to parse a String? Let us try it out. Assume you obtain a call log which consists of a start time and end time of every call separted by a ,. The start time and end time are separated by a |. Lets check the Sample Input & Output and write a code for the same. Use split function in String API

Create a main class "Main.java".
Create another class file "PhoneCalls.java" with the following members, 
Data type   Variable Name
Date    startTime
Date    endTime

Use appropriate getters and setters.

Input and Output Format:
Refer sample input and output for formatting specifications.

[All text in bold corresponds to input and the rest corresponds to output]

Sample Input:
Enter detail (start time1|end time1,start time2|end time2)
01:00:00|02:01:00,03:00:00|04:01:00

Sample Output:

Call Details

Number of calls made : 2

Call 1 :

Start Time : 01:00:00

End Time : 02:01:00

Call 2 :

Start Time : 03:00:00

End Time : 04:01:00

Program:

```
  package java1;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.ParseException;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.regex.Matcher;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;  
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  class PhoneCalls
 {
Date startTime;
Date endTime;
public Date getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}
public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}
public Date getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}
public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}
}
public class Main 
{
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException 
{
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter detail (start time1|end time1,start time2|end          time2)");
String str=s.nextLine();
String[] str1=str.split(",");
int a=str1.length;
System.out.println("Call Details");
System.out.println("Number of calls made : "+a);
PhoneCalls[] p=new PhoneCalls[a];
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    p[i]=new PhoneCalls();
    String[] str2=null;
    str2=str1[i].split("\\|");
    Date date1=null;
    date1=formatter.parse(str2[0]);
    Date date2=null;
    date2=formatter.parse(str2[1]);
    p[i].setStartTime(date1);
    p[i].setEndTime(date2);
}
for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
{
    System.out.println("Call "+(j+1)+" :");
    System.out.println("Start Time : "+p[j].startTime);
    System.out.println("End Time : "+p[j].endTime);
}
}
}


My  output:
Call Details
Number of calls made : 2
Call 1 :
Start Time : Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 IST 1970
End Time : Thu Jan 01 02:01:00 IST 1970
Call 2 :
Start Time : Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 IST 1970
End Time : Thu Jan 01 04:01:00 IST 1970

required output:
Call Details
Number of calls made : 2
Call 1 :
Start Time : 01:00:00
End Time : 02:01:00
Call 2 :
Start Time : 03:00:00
End Time : 04:01:00
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to what's important - "Create a main class" etc are really not part of the question. Then format your source code readably. Then work out how much of your code is actually relevant - if your question is *actually* only about formatting, you don't need the parsing part. Reduce it to a [mcve]. (Then read up on `SimpleDateFormatter`, which is probably what you want...)

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, you need to use the [SimpleDateFormatter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.text/newSimpleDateFormathhmmss.htm).

Your code should look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

for(int j = 0; j < a; j++)
{
    System.out.println("Call "+(j+1)+" :");
    System.out.println("Start Time : " + sdf.format(p[j].startTime));
    System.out.println("End Time : " + sdf.format(p[j].endTime));
}
```

Here the `SimpleDateFormatter` is used to format the output value of your `Date` object.

The complete code:

```
package nl.testing.startingpoint;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;  

class PhoneCalls
{
    Date startTime;
    Date endTime;

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }
    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
    public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}

public class Main 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter detail (start time1|end time1,start time2|end          time2)");

        String str = s.nextLine();
        String[] str1 = str.split(",");

        int a = str1.length;

        System.out.println("Call Details");
        System.out.println("Number of calls made : "+a);

        PhoneCalls[] p = new PhoneCalls[a];

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            p[i] = new PhoneCalls();

            String[] str2 = str1[i].split("\\|");

            Date date1 = formatter.parse(str2[0]);
            Date date2 = formatter.parse(str2[1]);

            p[i].setStartTime(date1);
            p[i].setEndTime(date2);
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

        for(int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Call "+(j+1)+" :");
            System.out.println("Start Time : " + sdf.format(p[j].startTime));
            System.out.println("End Time : " + sdf.format(p[j].endTime));
        }
    }
}
```